# Oracle Database- Trigger to Update and allocate randomly in one table based on insert in other table

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have 3 database tables:

```
BOOKING
CREATE TABLE BOOKING
(BOOKING_ID NUMBER,DETAILS VARCHAAR2(1000),
CONSTRAINT BOOKING_PK PRIMARY KEY ("BOOKING_ID"));

ALLOCATION
CREATE TABLE ALLOCATION
(ALLOCATION_ID NUMBER, BOOKING_ID NUMBER, STAFF_ID NUMBER,
CONSTRAINT ALLOCATION_PK PRIMARY KEY ("ALLOCATION_ID"));


STAFF
CREATE TABLE STAFF 
(STAFF_ID NUMBER,STAFF_TYPE VARCHAR2(20),
CONSTRAINT STAFF_PK PRIMARY KEY("STAFF_ID"));
```

So, whenever there is a new entry in the BOOKING table with a new Booking_ID, in the ALLOCATION table, that booking id would be allocated a Staff who is an Assistant(not manager) randomly.
One staff can be alloted multiple bookings also.

So, if there is a Booking ID 20.
In ALLOCATION Table: Allocation_id 1(generated via sequence), Booking_id = 20, Staff_id(Staff_id of any staff who is an assistant)

I need to create a trigger based on the above requirement.

Oracle 19c

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include **YOUR** attempt at a solution, the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution and a [MRE] including `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables and `INSERT` statements for your sample data. StackOverflow is not a code writing service where we do your homework for you; **YOU** need to put a minimal amount of effort in first to attempt a solution and then we can help with debugging it.

Comment: What is the logic to pick the STAFF_ID. I don't think you want to pick the same STAFF_ID every time.

Comment: One staff id can be allocated to multiple bookings. it can be picked randomly. Just that the Staff has to be assistant

Comment: If the assignment is _truly_ "random" it means you could logically end up making _all_ assignments to the same staff member.  The only way to prevent over/under loading a specific staff member is to have a balancing algorithm, not a truly random choice.  But as @MT0 said, you need to show some effort on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below trigger -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_INSERT_BOOKING
AFTER INSERT ON BOOKING
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO ALLOCATION(ALLOCATION_ID, BOOKING_ID, STAFF_ID)
     VALUES(YOUR_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,
            :NEW.BOOKING_ID,
            (SELECT STAFF_ID
               FROM STAFF
              WHERE STAFF_TYPE = 'Assistant'
              ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
              FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY));
END;
/
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e4a2a0f239060246ca2b89eb10857a81)